# Desktop won't load up

Tags: ati, thinkpad

Let me start off by saying that I am a complete newbie of all things Linux. I have an old IBM ThinkPad t30 i wanted to install and learn up. I downloaded the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 13.04. I installed it and everything was looking good.

The problem comes in after I login. The screen becomes grainy and I do not see anything icons/menu, etc on the desktop. The same background picture looks good on the disk install screen. I would have thought if this were just a video card issue the signin screen would be high quality and I would see something kind of icon or menu on the desktop.

As a side note, I do notice when I enter in the command prompt I see "Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-19-generic i686)" – could that mean I downloaded the 64 bit version even though it was labeled as the 32 bit version?

Any thoughts?

- Computer: IBM ThinkPad t30
- Video: ATI Mobility Radeon 7500
- Processor:  Mobile Intel(R) Mobile Pentium(R) 4 Processor-M
- Wireless: Hawking Technology (working fine)
- Computer’s detailed specs: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-58227

Comment: "could that mean I downloaded the 64 bit version even though it was labeled as the 32 bit version?" I think you are confused by `i686`, right? `i686` is 32-bit (it's an improved version of `i386`, which is 32-bit)

Comment: Yes, that is what was confusing me - just wasn't positive it was right. Thank you MiJyn.

Answer (score 0):

Your ThinkPad T30 is a 32-Bit one and a bit "antique" - but really a good one.
You could try Lubuntu as 32-Bit-CD, because with xfce-windows-manager it is not demanding too much memory for graphics like gnome or KDE do.

Comment: Definitely getting a lot further with Lubuntu. I actually get a desktop. Thanks Dschinn.